# Is there javascript (prefer jquery) library that automatically maps form elements to JSON?

Tags: html, json, forms, translation

**Background:** This is something I have been looking for since before even JSON was known as JSON.

Suppose you have the following javascript variable inside your code:

```
jsonroot = 
{
    'fname':'valued'
    ,'lname':'customer'
    ,faves:['berry','chocolate','mint']
    ,actors:[
        {'fname':'brad','lname':'pitt'}
        ,{'fname':'mike','lname':'hammer'}
    ]
};
```

You can easily see how this maps to JSON, it is a 1:1 correspondence.

**Question:** Is there a library that can take this 1:1 correspondence and carry it over to HTML Form elements? For example, I would like to do something like this inside a FORM element:

```
<input type="text" mapping="jsonroot['fname']" id="fname"></input>
<input type="text" mapping="jsonroot['lname']" id="lname"></input>

<legend>
    <fieldset>Favorite Flavors</fieldset>
    <input type="text" mapping="jsonroot['faves'][0]" id="fave_0"></input>
    <input type="text" mapping="jsonroot['faves'][1]" id="fave_1"></input>
    <input type="text" mapping="jsonroot['faves'][2]" id="fave_2"></input>
</legend>

<legend>
    <fieldset>Favorite Actors</fieldset>
    <input type="text" mapping="jsonroot['actors'][0]['fname']" id="fave_0_fname"></input>
    <input type="text" mapping="jsonroot['actors'][0]['lname']" id="fave_0_lname"></input>

    <input type="text" mapping="jsonroot['actors'][1]['fname']" id="fave_1_fname"></input>
    <input type="text" mapping="jsonroot['actors'][1]['lname']" id="fave_1_lname"></input>
</legend>
```

**Rationale:** Sometimes, instead of submitting form variables via POST or GET, I want to pass them into a javascript variable, then do something with the variable, and then send it somewhere.

Writing the HTML Form <-> JSON translation is tedious. I can't be the only person out there who has wanted to to this, so is there a library that handles this automatically?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like [Mark Gibson's JSON JQuery plugin](http://www.overset.com/2008/04/11/mark-gibsons-json-jquery-updated/). It adds `$.toJSON()` and `$.parseJSON()` methods. Use this in combination with code that serializes a form to an object such as [Serialize Form to JSON](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/serialize-form-to-json/):

> ```
> $.fn.serializeObject = function()
> {
>    var o = {};
>    var a = this.serializeArray();
>    $.each(a, function() {
>        if (o[this.name]) {
>            if (!o[this.name].push) {
>                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
>            }
>            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
>        } else {
>            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
>        }
>    });
>    return o;
> };
> ```